# why the requested link not showing up the nested component

Tags: reactjs

the nested Route in the following code is not working please need your help to solve out the issue.

the output is after click on a Course it will redirect me to the request link which will be for example:  localhost.com/course/1?title=blabla but the page is empty

App.js

```
<BrowserRouter>

      <div className="App">
          <header>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li ><NavLink to='/courses'>Courses</NavLink></li>
                        <li><Link to='/users'>Users</Link></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/courses' component={Courses} />
            <Route path='/users' component={Users}/>

        </Switch>

      </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Courses.js

```
CourseHandler=(id,title)=>{
    this.props.history.push({
        pathname: '/course/'+id,
        search:'?title='+title

    })
}

render () {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Amazing Udemy Courses</h1>
            <section  className="Courses">
                {
                    this.state.courses.map( course => {
                        return <article  key={course.id} className="Course" onClick={() => this.CourseHandler(course.id,course.title)}>{course.title}</article>
                    } )
                }
            </section>
             <Route path='/course/:id'  component={Course}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Issue**

Your main `Switch` doesn't have a route that matches the new one you just pushed.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path='/courses' component={Courses} />
  <Route path='/users' component={Users} />
</Switch>
```

Your course handler pushes a route your `Switch` doesn't match.

```
CourseHandler=(id,title)=>{
  this.props.history.push({
      pathname: '/course/'+id, // new route is "/course/xxxx", i.e. course is singular
      search:'?title='+title

  })
}
```

**Solution 1**

You can either move the route to the `Switch`

```
<Switch>
  <Route path='/courses' component={Courses} />
  <Route path='/course/:id' component={Course} />
  <Route path='/users' component={Users} />
</Switch>
```

**Solution 2**

Or update the new `Route` to include the path prefix already matched (I think this is what you intended, so the courses are still mapped)

```
render () {
  console.log(this.props)
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Amazing Udemy Courses</h1>
      <section  className="Courses">
        {
          this.state.courses.map( course => {
            return (
              <article
                key={course.id}
                className="Course"
                onClick={() => this.CourseHandler(course.id, course.title)}
              >
                {course.title}
              </article>
            );
          })
        }
      </section>
      <Route path='/courses/:id' component={Course}/> // updates to plural "courses" so it can match the outer route
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Solution 3**

A third option is to switch your `Switch` for a regular `Router` so multiple matches can be returned instead of *just* the first one.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

...

<Router>
  <Route path='/courses' component={Courses} /> // this one displays the courses list
  <Route path='/courses/:id' component={Course} /> // then this displays the specific course
  <Route path='/users' component={Users} />
</Router>
```